# Rest & Soap transactional capability

Tags: rest, soap

In one interview, interviewer asked, What is transactional capability,out of soap and rest which is having transactional capabilities?

could you please explain me in simple way.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Had come across these references when I ran into similar questions. Hope it helps.

- From http://spf13.com/post/soap-vs-rest

  > **WS-AtomicTransaction** 
  >    Need ACID Transactions over a service, you’re going to need SOAP. While REST supports transactions, it isn’t as
  >   comprehensive and isn’t ACID compliant. Fortunately ACID transactions
  >   almost never make sense over the internet. REST is limited by HTTP
  >   itself which can’t provide two-phase commit across distributed
  >   transactional resources, but SOAP can. Internet apps generally don’t
  >   need this level of transactional reliability, enterprise apps
  >   sometimes do.
- From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942839.aspx

  > **What about transactions?**
  >
  > Here is another area in which SOAP and WS-* have explicit support for
  >   an "advanced" feature and REST has none. WS-Atomic Transactions
  >   supports distributed, two-phase commit transactional semantics over
  >   SOAP-based services. REST has no support for distributed transactions.
  >   Generally speaking, if you want something like transactions in a
  >   RESTful system, you create a new resource. (Creating a new resource
  >   whenever you run into a problem with a RESTful system generally solves
  >   most problems.) You can have a resource called Transaction. When your
  >   client needs to do something transactional (such as transferring money
  >   between two bank accounts), the client creates a Transaction resource
  >   that specifies all the correct resources affected (in my example, the
  >   two bank accounts) by doing a POST to the Transaction factory URI. The
  >   client can then perform updates by sending a PUT to the transaction
  >   URI and close the transaction by sending a DELETE to the URI.
  >
  > This, of course, requires some amount of hand-coding and explicit
  >   control over your system, whereas the WS-Atomic Transactions system is
  >   more automatic because (in the case of Windows Communication
  >   Foundation) it is tied to your runtime's plumbing.
  >
  > If your system absolutely needs atomic transactional semantics across
  >   diverse systems, WS-Atomic Transactions is probably the way to go.
  >   Using distributed transactions in this way may or may not be smart
  >   because it increases the coupling between the two systems and creates
  >   potential problems if you aren't controlling the code on both ends.
  >   But the most important thing is to use the right tool for the right
  >   job (once you've figure out what the right job is). In defense of
  >   REST, I think it is fair to say that given today's distributed,
  >   service-oriented architectures, coupling two endpoints so tightly
  >   using a distributed transaction may not be the best design. On the
  >   other hand, some situations call for this type of functionality, and
  >   if you need it, use SOAP and WS-Atomic Transactions.